# Fitting cubes inside a bigger cube

Tags: packing-problem, combinatorial-geometry

Suppose the sum of the volumes of $n$ cubes is 1. Then no matter what $n$ is I need to prove they can be put inside a cube of volume $\leq 2$ such that they do not overlap.

I am totally going nuts on how to approach this one.

Comment: Try the $2$-dimensional version of this problem first. Essentially, you order them from big to small, put the biggest ones in first on the bottom, then stack them on a new "level" once you run out of room on the bottom, then repeat this until done. Some clever algebra shows this always work.

Comment: The 2-dimensional version came up at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109280/can-a-finite-number-of-squares-with-total-area-at-most-1-be-fitted-into-a-squa?

Comment: I don't see that this can be done for $n=2$. How are you going to fit two cubes of side 79 inside a cube of side 126?

Comment: @BrianTrial: It is the volumes, not the surface areas, that must sum to $1$. Also, the volume of a cube of side $2$ is $8$, which is not $\leqslant2.$.

Comment: Thanks John, I realize my mistake now.  Perhaps it could still be an interesting problem restated:  What is the smallest volume of a cube that can contain all the other cubes no matter what n is?