# is it always possible to place $4$ different squares on a square board with area $1$ without overlapping?

Tags: geometry

Given $4$ different squares such that the sum of their areas equals $0.5$ , is it always possible to place them on a square board with area $1$ without overlapping?
What if there were $5$ different squares such that the sum of their areas equals 0.5?
I think it is given that
$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=0.5$

By considering
$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=(a+b+c+d)^2-2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)$

I want to prove  $a+b+c+d <1$

Comment: $a+b+c+d<1$ would mean that you are placing all four squares one after the other (a kind of $1\times4$ grid). This does not have to be the case. You could place two squares on the same row, and the other two on another row ($2\times2$ grid).

Comment: The inequality $a+b+c+d < 1$ is false in general. For example the squares with the sides $a=b=0.49$, $c=d=0.05$ have total area smaller than $0.5$ and they do all fit into a square.

Comment: I would try to fit them in the corners rather than in row

Comment: I remember the following American Mathematical Monthly problem: "Given a collection of squares whose total area is $1$, prove that
they can be placed into a square of side $\sqrt{2}$ without overlapping."

Comment: @ChristianBlatter that's a special case of Moon-Moser theorem. see refs in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/109441/59379)

Answer (score 3):

I will prove that we can put all four squares in the corners of the large square, without intersections.  If $a,b,c,d<\frac12$, then we can do this, so  we may suppose that $a$ is the largest square, and that $a\geq\frac12.$  Place $a$ in one of the corners.  If some square $x$ cannot be placed  in another corner with intersecting square $a$, then $x\geq1-a.$  The toatl area of these two squares is at least $$f(a)=a^2+(1-a)^2= 2a^2-2a+1$$

Now $f\left(\frac12\right)=\frac12$ and $f'(a)=4a-2\geq0$ when $a\geq\frac12.$  These means that the sum of the areas of these two squares is at least $\frac12$ so that the sum of the areas of all four squares is greater than $\frac12$, contradicting the hypothesis.  Therefore, no square can intersect square $a$.  Since the other three squares are all smaller than $1-a\leq\frac12$, they cannot intersect one another, either.

Comment: @DavidK What I meant was that since $b$ doesn't intersect $a$ and $c$ is smaller than $a$, then $b$ can't intersect $c$ either, but I agree that your formulation is simpler.  Thanks.